# How to link a table to a field a in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have this data from a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<words>
    <id>...</id>
    <word>...</word>
    <meaning>...</meaning>
    <translation>
        <ES>...</ES>
        <PT>...</PT>
    </translation>
</words>
```

This forms the table named "words", which has four fields ("id","word","meaning" and "translation"). On the other hand, the "translation" field can hold several languages like ES,PT,EN,JA,KO,etc... So I create a table ("words.translation", one field is "id" and the others ones are languages ids like "ES","PT",...).

I'm sorry for this newby question, but I'd like to know a couple of things about this one-to-many relationship.

1. How to join (or link?) this two tables in MySQL?
2. What information does the "translation" field in the "words" table has to store?
3. How is the sql query to get all the word information (JOIN syntax used?)

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer ...

1. *How to join (or link?) this two tables in MySQL?*

You can link the two tables by declaring a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) between the 'word_id' in the TRANSLATION table and the 'id' field in in the WORD table.

2. What information does the "translation" field in the "words" table has to store?

since there are many translations and only one 'original' word in the design you propose, the link will be from translation (many) to word (one), the link is the 'word_id' I mentioned under *1*. 
Please note that a different design with only one single table that contains 'word,meaning,language' and a meaning_id to self-join translations, might be better for words with multiple translations/meanings.

3. How is the sql query to get all the word information (JOIN syntax used?)

assuming two tables, word and translation, the syntax would be

```
select w.word, w.meaning, t.language, t.word 
  from WORD as w
  join TRANSLATION as t 
    on (w.id = t.word_id)
```

---

**caveat:** your design assumes that there will always be a on to one translation from one language to another. Un?-fortunately that is not true.

Each word has a set of co-meanings that differ from language to language, your meaning field implies that you are aware of this.

---

Table **WORD**: id | word | meaning
    PK on word_id

Table **TRANSLATION** word_id | language  | word
    PK on (word_id,language), FK word_id -> WORD

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
You are right, I didn't considered the co-meanings so the design isn't too useful. I'm confused now, though.

The idea of the db is to store 1.the meanings of words of a single language (e.g. English) and 2.their translations to multiple languages.
So a translation per meaning of a word would be more convenient, right?

In that case a "Word", "Meaning" and "Translation" tables are necesary.

Comment: @Nek: I would go for a 'WORD', a 'MEANING' table and an n:m Link-Table, that joins them. A translation is just another WORD, in another language, where both words are LINK-ed to the same meaning.

Comment: I'm sorry what is a n:m Link-Table? The translation is a word but in this case it's quite different. the words in the WORD table have other fields like Kanji and Kana (other characters) and the translation don't.

Comment: @Nek: I've added a second answer with my design suggestion. LINK is the n:m table that joins 'n' words to 'm' meanings (a many-to-many relationship).

Comment: @Nek: re(Kanji and Kana) If you are certain that 'Translation' is quite different from word, then you could use a table for each. It is sometimes hard to decide where generalization (my 'alternate' design) is not better then a situtation-dedicated design. Possible you will never need to know the co-meanings. It depend on the original set of requirements that the DB design needs to meet.

Answer (score 0):

an alternate Design, based on our discussion in the comments to my previous answer:

- Table **WORD:** (WORD_ID | WORD | LANGUAGE)
         PK on (WORD_ID)
- Table **MEANING:** (MEANING_ID | MEANING) 
         PK on MEANING_ID
- Table **LINK:**  (WORD_ID | MEANING_ID) 
         PK on (WORD_ID,MEANING_ID) 
   **Desciption** This table is a many-to-many relationship. One word con have multiple meanings (in the same language) and one meaning can have multiple words (in one or more languages)

---

Please note that the 'same' word in different languages no longer carries the same word_id

Comment: I was thinking something like:

WORD: (WORD_ID | WORD | MEANING_ID)

MEANING: (MEANING_ID | MEANING | TRANSLATION_ID)

TRANSLATION: (TRANSLATION_ID | LANGUAGE | TRANSLATION)

Comment: @Nek: Why don't you try out which design fits best? Write some simple examples of the DB onto a piece sheat of paper and 'walk' through imaginary code that handles the data. The data design that leads to the simplest / easiest understood & explained code, is likely what you need!

Comment: Thank you again for your invaluable help. I see that your design its more efficient. I'll keep it in mind. One last question, do I need to declare a foreign key to use the code above? (select ... join...)